# How do I find the line in a text file beginning with 5678 and replace it with nothing using php?

Tags: php, replace

Lets say the text file contains:

```
56715:Jim:12/22/10:19  
5678:Sara:9/04/08:92    
53676:Mark:12/19/10:6  
56797:Mike:12/04/10:123  
5678:Sara:12/09/10:49  
56479:Sammy:12/12/10:645  
56580:Martha:12/19/10:952
```

I would like to find the lines beginning with "5678" and replace them with nothing, so the file will now contain only:

```
56715:Jim:12/22/10:19  
53676:Mark:12/19/10:6  
56797:Mike:12/04/10:123  
56479:Sammy:12/12/10:645  
56580:Martha:12/19/10:952
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// The filename
$filename = 'filename.txt';

// Stores each line into an array item
$array = file($filename);

// Function to return true when a line does not start with 5678
function filter_start($item)
{
   return !preg_match('/^5678:/', $item);
}

// Runs the array through the filter function
$new_array = array_filter($array, 'filter_start');

// Writes the changes back to the file
file_put_contents($filename, implode($new_array));
```

Comment: If you're going to iterate, I'd do `return strpos($item, '5678') !== 0` instead of the regex, as it's just a simple string comparison vs loading the entire regex on each iteration...

Comment: @ircmaxell: I personally find the regex easier to read, meaning I can quickly determine what it's doing. It can also be edited down the line to match other requirements that might arise.

Comment: fair enough, but I try to follow the rule that you should never use a regex when a simple string operation will do the same job.

Comment: What if "5678" is a variable like: $_var1. Would I do: return !preg_match('/^$_var1:/', $item);

Answer (score 3):

Well, just use preg_replace:

```
$data = file_get_contents($filename);
$data = preg_replace('/^5678.*(\n|$)/m', '', $data);
```

Note the `m` modifier.  That puts PCRE into multiline mode, where `^` matches the start of the document, and after any new-line character (and `$` matches the end of the document, and before any new-line character)...

Also, depending on your *exact* needs, you *could* create a [stream filter](http://us.php.net/manual/en/stream.filters.php):

```
class LineStartFilter extends php_user_filter {
    protected $data = '';
    protected $regex = '//';
    public function filter($in, $out, &$consumed, $closing) {
        var_dump($this->regex);
        while ($bucket = stream_bucket_make_writeable($in)) {
            $bucket->data = preg_replace($this->regex, '', $bucket->data);
            $consumed += $bucket->datalen;
            stream_bucket_append($out, $bucket);
        }
        return PSFS_PASS_ON;
    }
    public function onCreate() {
        list($prefix, $data) = explode('.', $this->filtername);
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->regex = '/^'.preg_quote($data, '/').'.*(\n|$)/m';
    }
}
stream_filter_register('linestartfilter.*', 'LineStartFilter');
```

Then, just do this when you want to read the file:

```
$f = fopen('test.txt', 'r');
stream_filter_append($f, 'linestartfilter.5678');
fpassthru($f);
fclose($f);
```

That will output your requested string.  And if you want to write to another file (copy it):

```
$f = fopen('test.txt', 'r');
stream_filter_append($f, 'linestartfilter.5678');
$dest = fopen('destination.txt', 'w');
stream_copy_to_stream($f, $dest);
fclose($f);
fclose($dest);
```

Comment: Just wondering, will that regex consume the last `\n`, or will it leave it there?

Comment: @Alex: It will leave it there, if you want it consumed, just change the regex to `/^5678.*(\n|$)/`

Comment: The OP's sample output says they should be removed.

Answer (score 2):

`preg_replace('~5678:[^\n]+?\n~', '', $text);`

If your text ends with `\n`, otherwise convert the line endings first.

Comment: You could probably do `preg_replace('~5678:[^\n]+?' . preg_quote(PHP_EOL, '~') . '~', '', $text);`. The second `preg_quote()` argument is only necessary if end of line characters someday include `~`, which I doubt.

Comment: @alex, the file I'm parsing must not have the PHP_EOL endings, maybe it was uploaded by the user who's using a different platform. Or am I wrong?

Comment: `PHP_EOL` will be native to your platform, so maybe they are different. Also, I didn't notice the `[^\n]`. If you make it the ungreedy match all, you can drop it. Either way, I like your solution so +1

Answer (score 2):

[Tim Cooper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/142162/tim-cooper) just [reminded me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085513/how-do-i-find-the-line-in-a-text-file-beginning-with-5678-and-replace-it-with-not/5085557#5085557) what `file()` does :)

```
$lines = file($filename);

$lines = preg_grep('/^5678/', $lines, PREG_GREP_INVERT);

$file = implode($lines);

file_put_contents($filename, $file);
```